# Express routes for API - URL handlers when you have sub resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have two resources, employees and employee groups. I'm trying to implement a nice URL structure like:

- `GET /employees` List employees.
- `GET /employees/123` Get employee 123.
- `GET /employees/groups` List employee groups.
- `GET /employees/groups/123` Get employee group 123.

Using ExpressJS I have:

```
router.get('/employees', (req, res, next) => { next(); });
router.get('/employees/:id', (req, res, next) => { next(); });
router.get('/employees/groups', (req, res, next) => { next(); });
router.get('/employees/groups/:id', (req, res, next) => { next(); });
router.all('*', (req, res) => { res.send('...'); });
```

This doesn't work, because Express can't tell the difference between `/employees/:id` and `/employees/groups`. It thinks `groups` is an `id` because `/employees/:id` comes first.

I did have URL's like:

- `GET /employees`
- `GET /employees/123`
- `GET /employees-groups`
- `GET /employees-groups/123`

Which works, but doesn't have the nice resource/sub-resource format. The `groups` are groups of `employees` and so I'd like the URL's to match that.

If I were getting the groups for an employee it would be fine (`/employees/:id/groups`), but I'm getting all groups, which are employee groups.

How could I set up Express routes to route properly while still keeping the URL structure I want..?

I guess I need a way for Express to distinguish between an `id` and a sub-resource. Is there any way to do that..?

**UPDATE**

I obviously should've said that I'm using `next()` in each handler, because I need Express to move onto another middleware function, one that controls the response of all requests. It's this other middleware function that actually sends a response. So I need:

1. Handler for the route.
2. Handler for all requests.

Comment: Just let me add that `/nesting/like/this` doesn't make it any *nicer*. `/employees-groups/` simply makes sense. Look at the explanation you gave: *get employee group 123*. It clearly is a different resource. Give it its own url

Comment: I guess "nicer" is subjective. I think it's nicer, you don't. I want the URL to match the hierarchical structure of the resources - these are groups of employees - so they're related, and it would be "nice" :-) if the URL showed that.

Comment: It sure is :) Having your url-mapping code just do that and not have a fix for an unconventional case could be argued to be nicer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RobbyD set me on the right track. This is what I've ended up with:

#### index.js

```
router.all('*', setupHandler);
router.get('/employees', getEmployees);
router.get('/employees/groups', getGroups);
router.get('/employees/groups/:id', getGroup);
router.get('/employees/:id', getEmployee);
router.use(errorHandler);
```

#### setupHandler()

```
function setupHandler(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.standardRes = {
        "some": "data"
    };
    res.locals.doResponse = (res) => {
        // ...
        res.json(res.locals.standardRes);
    };
    next();
}
```

#### getEmployees()

```
function getEmployees(req, res, next) {

    somethingThatReturnsAPromise().then(data => {
        // add to res.locals.standardRes here
        res.locals.doResponse(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        next(err);
    });

}
```

#### errorHandler()

```
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('err', err);
    // add to res.locals.standardRes here
    // set correct res.status here
    res.locals.doResponse(res);
}
```

So the handlers are in the order in RobbyD's answer. I've used `res.locals` to hold a response function (`doResponse(res)`) to call from each handler. If there's an error I call `next(err)` as normal to move to `errorHandler()`.

I guess it's all about getting the right flow from middleware to middleware and sending the response at the right time.

Answer (score 4):

Express searches for the first route that matches and handles it with the provided function.

Try the other way around:

```
router.get('/employees', (req, res) => {});
router.get('/employees/groups', (req, res) => {});
router.get('/employees/groups/:id', (req, res) => {});
router.get('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {});
```

Now express will work its way trough the routes, '/employees/123' will only match on the last route, so that one will be used by express. '/employees/groups' will be matched sooner by the second route and that one will be used.

Very simple but these things can cost you some time figuring out.

Comment: Thanks RobbyD! I've updated my question as I missed out a vital bit... Sorry! Your answer would indeed work if I wasn't using `next()`.

Comment: Why don't you pass that middleware that you're using to handle all requests explicitly? I think by just calling next() you're letting express continue, thus working it's way trough the following routes. If instead you'd assign your middleware to a variable and then calling that instead of next, you get what you want? var myMiddleware = require('crazymiddleware'). And then just: router.get('/employees/groups', (req, res, myMiddleware) => {});

Comment: You got me on the right track! I've posted how I actually solved this (using `res.locals`). I'm not sure trying to replace `next()` would work, I think you might just be renaming `next()` to `myMiddleware()`, not calling a different function.